# How to pass passwords in echo command?

Tags: linux, passwords, echo

I need to run a simple while loop as below and run a command recursively.

Ex :

```
while true; do echo command; sleep 10; done
```

But to execute `command`, I need to enter couple of passwords once after another. I don't want to enter these passwords repeatedly every time this command is executed in the terminal window. Please suggest.

I have tried something like below but it didn't work, as it is still asking for password.

Ex :

```
while true; do echo "password" | command; sleep 10; done
```

My requirement is, I need to run a command recursively multiple times in mac terminal and that command needs 2 passwords which I need to enter once after another. I don't to enter these passwords every time. Please suggest.